# Trying to read value from back4app object and set it to a variable but getting error: Cannot set property 'loginName' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, parse-platform, back4app, parse-javascript-sdk

This is my codde, writing it to the console works fine, error occurs when assign the value to a variable.

```
const User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
            const query = new Parse.Query(User);
            query.equalTo("username", this.userData.getUsername);
            query.first().then(function(myuser){
            if(myuser){
               this.loginName = myuser.get('username');
               console.log(this.loginName)
            } else {
               console.log("Nothing found, please try again");
            }
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " - " + error.message);       
        });
```

Comment: Replace `.then(function(myuser){` with `.then(myuser =>{`

Comment: Tq David, this solved my problem.